# Box with balls of different colours. Probability of finding a specific colour.

Tags: probability

A box has $10$ red balls and $5$ black balls. A ball is selected from the box. If the ball is red, it is returned to the box. If the ball is black, it and $2$ additional black balls are added to the box. Find the probability that a second ball selected from the box is

(a) red;

(b) black.

Call red $R$ and black $B$ and the subscripts $1$ and $2$ the first and second selection, respectively.

I have to find $P(R_2).$

$$P(R_2) = P((R_2 \cap B_1) \cup (R_2 \cap R_1)) = 
P(R_2 \cap B_1)  +  (R_2 \cap R_1) = \\ P(R_2 | B_1)P(B_1) + P(R_2 | R_1 )P(R_1) = \frac{10}{18} \frac{5}{15} + \frac{10}{15} \frac{10}{15} = \frac{17}{27}.$$

This is not the given answer however. What is wrong with my reasoning? Doing this for the black ball yields $10/27$.

Comment: Have you tried taking cases for the first ball and being red differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret the problem statement as saying that if the first ball drawn is black,
the number of black balls in the box before the second drawing will be $7$ 
($4$ that remained in the box after the first drawing, plus $1$ ball returned to the box, plus $2$ new black balls).

You seem to assume $8$ black balls in your value of $P(R_2\mid B_1).$

Comment: Yes that is precisely the problem.

Comment: @David K, Respected Mr. David, publish, please, the full solution to this problem.